# stormcrawler - stackoverflow error on parser bolt when http.content.limit is -1

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

Storm Crawler is running in a Kubernetes Cluster, and we are getting many StackOverFlow errors in JSoupParserBolt

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError at org.apache.xerces.dom.ParentNode.internalInsertBefore(Unknown Source) at org.apache.xerces.dom.ParentNode.insertBefore(Unknown Source) 
at org.apache.xerces.dom.NodeImpl.appendChild(Unknown Source) at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.parse.JSoupDOMBuilder.createDOM(JSoupDOMBuilder.java:111) 
at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.parse.JSoupDOMBuilder.createDOM(JSoupDOMBuilder.java:136) at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.parse.JSoupDOMBuilder.createDOM(JSoupDOMBuilder.java:136) 
at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.parse.JSoupDOMBuilder.createDOM(JSoupDOMBuilder.java:136) at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.parse.JSoupDOMBuilder.createDOM(JSoupDOMBuilder.java:136) 
at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.parse.JSoupDOMBuilder.createDOM(JSoupDOMBuilder.java:136) at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.parse.JSoupDOMBuilder.createDOM(JSoupDOMBuilder.java:136) 
at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.parse.JSoupDOMBuilder.createDOM(JSoupDOMBuilder.java:136) at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.parse.JSoupDOMBuilder.createDOM(JSoupDOMBuilder.java:136)
```

Crawler Topology is configured with

```
  worker.heap.memory.mb: 8062
  topology.worker.max.heap.size.mb: 8062
  http.content.limit: -1
```

may `http.content.limit: -1` be causing this issue?

Comment: can you identiify the URL which is causing it?

Comment: yes, it is weird because, it seems a simple blog, nothing special... but all the pages related with this blog are failing with same error

http://dbctan.blogspot.com/2006/12/

Comment: I realized that is happening with many urls , http://polloxniner.blogspot.com/ is causing same issue...

Answer (score 0):

*http.content.limit: -1* means that you will fetch a URL until you get to the end of its content. If a URL points to an endless stream e.g. online radio then the memory consumption will grow until the JVM crashes. This would give you an out of memory exception and it's probably not what's happening here.

EDIT: thanks for sharing the URLs. I can reproduce the problem, would you mind opening an issue on GitHub? Thanks!

CONCLUSION: this is not a bug as such, it's just that when fetching the whole documents (209 and 350Kb) the conversion from the JSoup document to DocumentFragments involves a lot of recursion and crashes the stack limit.
I managed to parse the 2 urls you gave by setting -Xss10M as VM arguments.